# Pass array(values) in magento event driven programming

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

My custom module controller `CartController.php`'s add method

```
public function addAction()
{
  ..........
  $params = array(); //array of important data
  //here in event dispatcher, along with other data, i want to send $params to my even observer
  Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete', array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()),$params);
  ........
}
```

My custom module's `config.xml`

```
<config>
   ........
   <frontend>
     ........
     <events>
        <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
            <observers>
                <frontendconfigurableproductmatrix>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>frontendconfigurableproductmatrix/observer</class>
                    <method>addToCartEvent</method>
                </frontendconfigurableproductmatrix>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
    </events>
    .........
 </frontend>
 ..........
</config>
```

Now, in my observer file `Observer.php`

```
 public function addToCartEvent($observer) {
       $params = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getParams();
       print_r($params); //prints nothing

       //but this below is printing data
       $request = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();
       print_r($request); //prints data
 }
```

How do i pass this $param array from my controllers `addAction` method event dispatcher to my observer file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass params like:

```
  Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete', array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse(),'my_params' => $params));
```

In the Observer method you can call

```
 public function addToCartEvent($observer) {
       $params = $observer->getMyParams()
       print_r($params);    
 }
```

The problem in your implementation was that you were passing $params to dispatchEvent array without a key. You need to add a key, like in my case I used my_params.